# Angular 8 Universal (Server Side Rendering) app is crashing

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I have deployed an Angular 8 universal app in a server droplet of Digital Ocean. It is running in production. The server config is 4GB memory and 2 vCPU. The app is run via nodejs in the server. It's been running fine for over a month until recently it suddenly started crashing in no definite time. Since it's running in my client's computer browser, I don't know any way to monitor the error in their console. I also run this app with NOHUP command which dumps all the server side node js logs in a nohup.out file. But nohup.out file shows nothing about the crash.

Things that happened around the crash event started to happen.
1. I have pushed an update which is totally unrelated to the bootstrapping of the app. As per my understanding the Angular universal only renders the initial view and sends it to client browser. After that it's the browser that takes care of rest of the jobs.

2. The app uses websocket to maintain a bidirectional connectivity with the backend app written in Java. Also I don't think WS is the reason, because after implementing the WS feature, it ran just fine for over a week.
3. Thirdly i noticed that there are some image links(of the website) that are loaded from a CDN/Edge server and for last couple of days some static files located in the CDN server are taking too long to load/download. The response time to load those files spike up to 25-26 seconds sometimes. Since these static files are loaded during startup, can the delay of loading the static files cause any type of timeout event when Node JS renders the page in the startup?

As you can understand I have no clue how to debug this thing. Is there anyway who faced similar crashing issue with Angular Universal and help me point to the right direction? Thanks